# Struggling to find solution: question 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$xy'-2y=\frac{x^6}{(y+x^2)}$$

Can someone please help with this one?

It looks like a bernoulli equation, I have tried to multiply both sides by denominator and gather them in parantheses to leave the $y'$ alone but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$xy'-2y=\frac{x^6}{(y+x^2)}$$
$$x^2y'-2xy=\frac{x^5}{(1+y/x^2)}$$
$$\left (\dfrac {y}{x^2}\right )'=\frac{x}{(1+y/x^2)}$$
It's separable:
$$\left ( \dfrac y{x^2}+1 \right)d\left (\dfrac {y}{x^2}+1\right )={x}dx$$
Integrate.
$$\boxed {\left ( \dfrac y{x^2}+1 \right)^2-x^2=C}$$

Comment: Could you help me with my other question too?

Comment: Are you sure you copied correctly the other differential equation you posted ? Because I see no solution @SirDancealot

Comment: Hundert percent, that is from exercise sheet professor gave us.

Comment: Then it's really hard to solve because I really tried and couldnt find the solution @SirDancealot

Comment: The problem is the term $+ ydy$/ The trig functions terms are ok @SirDancealot

Comment: Appreciate the effort.

Comment: You're welcome @SirDancealot i really tried yesterday to solve it but couldnt.

Comment: How would it be if it weren't for that $+y$ term though?

Comment: Man I owe you big time with this question, really. If we ever come across, (I assume you are in Germany) I will treat you a beer. Or whatever you like. In todays exam, same question came.

Comment: oh thank you @SirDancealot you're so kind with me. Yeah we could discuss math and drink beer. lol

Comment: And I wish you the best for your exams. You just need to practice again and again. @SirDancealot

Answer (score 1):

$xy'-2y=\dfrac{x^6}{y+x^2} \, $ i.e, $\displaystyle y'- \frac{2y}{x}=\dfrac{x^5}{y+x^2}$

LHS form is $y' + f(x)y = g(x)$.

Integrating factor $I = \displaystyle e^{\int f(x)dx} = e^{\int \frac{-2}{x}dx} = e^{-2 \, lnx} =  \frac{1}{x^2}$.

So, $\displaystyle \frac{y'}{x^2} - \frac{2y}{x^3}= \dfrac{x^3}{y+x^2}$

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\left({\frac{y}{x^2}}\right) = \dfrac{x}{(y/x^2)+1}$

It is straightforward from here.

Comment: Please see _Solving first order linear ordinary differential equations_ section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#:~:text=Navier%E2%80%93Stokes%20differential%20equations%20used%20to%20simulate%20airflow%20around%20an%20obstruction.&text=In%20mathematics%2C%20an%20integrating%20factor,a%20given%20equation%20involving%20differentials.

Comment: Could you say what 'LHS' is?

Comment: sorry I meant, left hand side of the expression

Comment: And you have gone to find its integration factor but the term on the right hand side doesn't only depend on x but y too and y's power is different than 0 or 1. So isn't there some substitutions to be made first like being done in case of Bernoulli equations?

Comment: yes but that becomes $(y/x^2) + 1$ in denominator which goes to the left and dx goes to the right. You can substitute $u = y/x^2$.

Comment: It becomes $(u+1) du = xdx$